# Weird exchange rate when buying DAI with Ether

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I wrote code to buy DAI using ETH on Uniswap V2 as follows:

```
function buyCryptoOnUniswap(uint256 etherCost , address cryptoToken) public payable returns(uint256){
//address cryptoToken = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;

require(etherCost <= address(this).balance , "Insufficient funds")



    uint256 cryptoAmountPurchasable = estimateTokensThatETHCanBuy(etherCost , cryptoToken)[1];
    cryptoAmountPurchasable = cryptoAmountPurchasable.mul(11).div(10);// multiply by 1.1
 
    uint deadline = now + 300; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!

   
    usi.swapExactETHForTokens.value(etherCost)(0, getPathForETHToToken(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);

   return cryptoAmountPurchasable;

}

 function estimateTokensThatETHCanBuy(uint ethAmount , address crypto) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
       return usi.getAmountsOut(ethAmount, getPathForETHToToken(crypto));
  }

  function getPathForETHToToken(address crypto) private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = usi.WETH();
    path[1] = crypto;
    
    return path;
  }
```

The code works but I was expecting an exchange rate of about 180 -> 230 but to my dismay, 0.1 ETH only gave me 1.926 DAI and 1 ETH gave me about 19.26 DAI also.

[Here is the transaction using 0.1ETH.](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xef37bbfe0ac27659f883f2c718ee9404bfd42b6b7d7f1420969dba62a8779da1)

I am using the DAI token for kovan: **0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa**.

Is something wrong with my code?

Please help.

**UPDATE**

I wrote code to buy DAI on Kyber and I got it at the expected rate range:

[See the transaction here.](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xb747e0ee4f61d8899daafa47b1e6d1ce5192fa5ce27c17c655e39608a717a40f)

Comment: Take a good look at `.mul(11).div(10);// divide by 1.1`

Comment: Hmm, true that...should be multiply by 1.1. Thanks. But it would still be off by a factor of at least 10, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're doing this on Kovan. The DAI/WETH uniswap pool on Kovan obviously doesn't use real (with value) DAI or WETH, so there is no arbitrage to push it to the market rate of ETH/DAI. See the pool [here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xb10cf58e08b94480fcb81d341a63295ebb2062c2) and look at the token amounts, ~660 kWETH and ~25,000 kDAI which gives a rate of ~38 DAI per ETH. The price has gone up since your test transaction, but it's just due to the testnet using valueless tokens

Comment: please could you help me out with this question?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84915/what-token-address-do-i-use-if-i-want-to-sell-an-erc20-token-on-a-different-exch/84919#84919